# stack columns in dataframe, and also stack index column

Tags: python, indexing, stack, pandas

I have a problem stacking columns from a dataframe in pandas and in addition stack a column and making it an indexcolumn that not contains unique values.

```
>>> ds
  respondent  brand engine  country  aware  aware_2  aware_3  age  volvo  resp
0          a  volvo      p      swe      1        0        1   23   True     1
1          b  volvo   None      swe      0        0        1   45   True     2
2          c    bmw      p       us      0        0        1   56  False     3
3          d    bmw      p       us      0        1        1   43  False     2
4          e    bmw      d  germany      1        0        1   34  False     1
5          f   audi      d  germany      1        0        1   59  False     2
6          g  volvo      d      swe      1        0        0   65   True     3
7          h   audi      d      swe      1        0        0   78  False     2
8          i  volvo      d       us      1        1        1   32   True     2
```

I would like to make a new dataframe with column `aware`,`aware_2` and `aware_3` and also with the column `resp` as stacked.

Comment: Could you clarify what you actually want? Stacked how? (can you give the first few lines?)

Comment: I would like to stack the dummy variables (aware,aware_2,aware_3), and also separately stack the resp variable and assosiate the stacked dummies with that variables. So it should be a new dataset with 2 stacked columns

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index(['aware', 'aware_2', 'aware_3', 'resp'])

In [12]: df1.columns.name = 'heading'

In [13]: df1.stack()
Out[13]:
aware  aware_2  aware_3  resp  heading
1      0        1        1     respondent          a
                               brand           volvo
                               engine              p
                               country           swe
                               age                23
                               volvo            True
0      0        1        2     respondent          b
                               brand           volvo
                               engine           None
                               country           swe
                               age                45
                               volvo            True
...
```

Comment: Actually no, I would like to have 2 columns in the dataframe, one with the stacked dummies and the other column (resp) stacked next to it